# How to build a working copy of Ogre3D 2.1 for CodeLite using the MinGW compiler on Windows 10 32-bit

Tags: compiler-errors, ogre

For the past few days, I've been working through a problem building Ogre3D. The platform I am compiling on supports Opengl Embedded Systems 2 natively, but these headers do not appear to be a part of the dependencies package for Ogre.

---

> ## Solved Problems

- #### Cmake's CodeLite Generator has a Known Bug<sup>1</sup>

The project is built using cmake and it is worth noting that all the cmake generators for CodeLite set the project to build with the `-j 0` option which is nonsensical; you can't compile with *no* threads. This means that it is necessary to navigate to *each project* -- of which there are 9 or 10 depending on whether you manage to include `ogredeps` -- and remove the argument 4 times from each `.project` file. When this occurs, the compiler makes a point of explaining this error with the message that *`the '-j' option requires a positive integral argument`* and ceases compilation.

I've created a primitive script to automate this process, and which executes in less than a minute. It is available on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hTzYhDDK). Simply install the Python 2.7 interpreter and place the script at the root directory of your Ogre build, then run it.

---

- #### SDL2 OpenGL Embedded Systems Dependencies are not Included

While compiling the SDL2 portion of the dependencies, I receive the following compiler error:

```
C:/OGRE/Dependencies/src/SDL2/include/SDL_opengles2.h:33:31:
    fatal error:
        GLES2/gl2platform.h:
            No such file or directory
```

I found a post on the forums in which a user offers a [dubious solution](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=72461&start=250#p516918) of commenting out the offending includes. Naturally, this results in many code errors due to missing the referenced libraries.

After finding the [FAQ for 2.1](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page_ref_id=2191#What_about_GLES_support_), it appears that the Opengl ES 2 is not supported:

> #### What about GLES support?
>
> The plan is to eventually fix the now-broken GLES2 renderer, supporting both GLES2 and GLES3. However the idea for GLES2 is to support it for compatibility since it's a very ill-designed API but sadly present in millions of Android devices and isn't suited for high performance. So the focus will be more about compatibility and stability rather than performance (it should still be faster than it was in Ogre 1.x anyway). There may be other limitations we can't predict yet. 
>   With GLES3, it should be much easier to run performance oriented mobile applications.

As a temporary solution, I have placed the OpenGL ES include files from QtANGLE (part of Qt 5.7) into the cmake generated /Dependencies/build/src/SDL2-prefix/src/SDL2-build/include directory. I then modified the relevant includes of SDL_opengles2.h to be local includes:

```
#include "GLES2/gl2platform.h"
#include "GLES2/gl2.h"
#include "GLES2/gl2ext.h"
...
#include SDL_opengls2_khrplatform.h"
#include SDL_opengls2_gl2platform.h"
#include SDL_opengls2_gl2.h"
#include SDL_opengls2_gl2ext.h"
```

I am probably making a mistake with the linking of proper system include paths to allow the `#include <...>` syntax or, due to cmake, the global includes are being ignored. <sup><sup><sup>Occam's Razor suggests I don't know what I'm doing...</sup></sup></sup>

This solution corrected the problem and the compilation of Ogre *Dependencies* completed. However, Ogre does not compile.

---

- #### Writing Output to Blank: Invalid Argument

I am encountering another compiler error:

```
C:/OGRE/OgreMain/src/Win32/OgreWinResources.rc:11:0:
    fatal error:
        when writing output to : //not a typo; it's legitimately writing to a null file
            Invalid Argument
```

Shortly after termination, the compiler outputs one more related error:

```
C:\TDM-GCC-32\bin\windres.exe: 
    can't open file 'page:':
        Invalid Argument
C:\TDM-GCC-32\bin\windres.exe:
    preprocessing failed.
```

This one was very difficult to debug. It turns out that the only results for this -- after google-filter-fu -- were [on Russian websites](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22can%27t+open+file+%27page:%27%22+windres.exe). A hunch made me consider the possibility that it was a result of my using the windows utf-8 codepage (65001) by default for all command windows.

I read further and that's [exactly](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/12219455?cid=12327442) what it was. `chcp 65001` being executed in the terminal prior to compilation causes the weird bug. There are two solutions; stop swapping the codepage via a registry entry, or have `chcp 1252 &&` before any make commands. The cmake_fixer file I created may be modified to automate this process, but I found the easiest solution was to temporarily remove the registry modification I used.

---

> ## Current Problems

- #### MinGWSupport can't Resolve D3D11 Types Before Compiling<sup>2, 3</sup>

  ```
  C:/OGRE/OgreMain/include/WIN32/OgreMinGWSupport.h:48:29:
      error:
          'IID_totype' was not declared in this scope
  # define __uuidof(Object) IID_##Object
                            ^ 
  C:/Ogre/RenderSystems/Direct3D11/include/OgreD3D11Texture.h:99:47:
      note:
          in expansion of macro '__uuidof'
  HRESULT hr = from->QueryInterface(__uuidof(totype), (void **)to);
  ```

Looking at the source, I suspect this may be conflict due to the execution order of macros and templates. `template<typename fromtype, typename totype>` seems to indicate that the intent is to execute it *before* the macro substitution `__uuidof(totype)`. This is in contrast to the fact that the preprocessor substitutes macros before the compiler handles templates.

---

#### Footnotes

1. [Codelite generated build commands fail because of "-j 0" argument to mingw32-make](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15054)
2. [Build error in OgreD3D11Texture.h using MinGW](https://ogre3d.atlassian.net/browse/OGRE-148)
3. [Unable to build D3D9 plugin with mingw-w64 and Ogre 1.9 RC2](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=79265)